# GHUnit - Terminal - "BAD CPU type in executable"

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode5

GHUnit scripts running on terminal shows "BAD CPU type in executable" . It executes on device and simulator through XCode but shows CPU error on terminal.

Refered: http://gabriel.github.io/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_command_line.html
Tried Resetting the device network settings

Using Xcode5, iOS7 with Wifi network

Is there any other possibility to run the ghunit test scripts through commandline?

Comment: When executing the RunScript.sh as chmod u+X, "BAD cpu type executable" error is not shown. Rather build is passed, but app is not running

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are working with the simulator and not a real device, and valid archs include also i386.

From my [blog](http://mobiledevtest.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/ios-testing-from-command-line-through.html)

I found a good workaround that works for me with a simulator.
Just change the main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GHUnitIOS/GHUnitIOSViewController.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int retVal;
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (getenv("GHUNIT_CLI")) {
            retVal = [GHTestRunner run];
        } else {
            retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"GHUnitIOSAppDelegate");
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

---

### Editted: I succeeded to run on device from a command line, here are the steps:

---

From my [blog](http://mobiledevtest.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/ios-how-to-run-application-from-command.html)

1. use tool [ideviceinstaller](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller) to install into your device

   `ideviceinstaller -i <your app>.ipa`
2. Get Application folder in device (in order to keep the xml files)

   app_path=`ideviceinstaller -l -o xml | grep <your app>.app | sed 's/.*<string>\(.*\)<your app>.app<\/string>/\1/'`
3. run test application into device (don't save on tmp folder, the tmp folder is deleted when archive it) and keep XML into "Caches" folder. (use [idevice-app-runnner](https://github.com/crackleware/idevice-app-runner) tool)

   `idevice-app-runner -s com.<org>.<your scheme> -DGHUNIT_CLI=YES -DGHUNIT_AUTORUN=YES -DGHUNIT_AUTOEXIT=YES -DWRITE_JUNIT_XML=YES -DJUNIT_XML_DIR=$app_path/Library/Caches/test-results`
4. get archive app from device (to extract the xml files) - After the test application finished to run

   `ideviceinstaller -a com.<org>.<your scheme> -o copy=. -o remove`
5. `mv com.<org>.<your app>.ipa <any app name>.zip`
6. `unzip -o <any app name>.zip`
7. `cp Container/Library/Caches/test-results/*.* <your folder to keep the result xml files>`

Comment: When executing the RunScript.sh as chmod u+X, "BAD cpu type executable" error is not shown. Rather build is passed, but app is not running

Comment: Without chmod u+X, it works fine in Simulator. But on device it shows "Bad cpu type error". Is there any other way to run Ghunit on terminal thereby to integrate with Jenkins

Comment: When running on a device, you don't need the RunTests.sh but you need to run your application as above (note: the xml results are stored into application folder on device): idevice-app-runner -s com.<org>.<your scheme> -DGHUNIT_CLI=YES -DGHUNIT_AUTORUN=YES -DGHUNIT_AUTOEXIT=YES -DWRITE_JUNIT_XML=YES -DJUNIT_XML_DIR=$app_path/Library/Caches/test-results